# slack send message [ERROR] missing required field: channel

Tags: slack-api

I am trying to test sending message to channel via bot (App, to be exact.)

My query in Postman:
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage/ (there is token in headers)
and body
{"channel":"XXX","text":"I hope the tour went well, Mr. Wonka."}

But as result
{
"ok": false,
"error": "invalid_arguments",
"response_metadata": {
"messages": [
"[ERROR] missing required field: channel"
]
}
}

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and my problem was that I was doing GET instead of POST. Now it works for me.

Comment: Saved a lot of my time ty lol

Answer (score 2):

I had to set

```
content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

The charset mattered.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your content-type header. It should be "application/json" instead of "plain/text"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it is, but still error

Comment: can you share your code? I believe you're missing content-type, Because I faced this error some days ago, I set content-type for HttpClient header but for some reason it was replaced, so I need to set content-type for payload (I used StringContent)

Comment: as i metioned in post, i am using postman for this, so let me try to show my query like this:
POST : https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage/
headers: Content-Type - application/json and Authorization - Bearer xxxxx

Body (raw option): {"channel":"xxx","text":"I hope the tour went well, Mr. Wonka."}

Comment: in the raw body did you choose the JSON option instead of default Text option?

Comment: yes, it is JSON option

Comment: make sure you added role chat:write for bot token? 
or chat:write chat:write:user chat:write:bot if you used user token.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I was getting this because I was calling

```
POST https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage/
```

The issue is in the last `/`. So the correct call is:

```
POST https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

#### EXTRA:

Here are my headers:

```
{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'charset': 'utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_INSIDE_WITHOUT_CURLY_BRACKETS}'
}
```

and my body (make sure to put the # before the name of the channel).

```
{
        'test': 'YOUR_TEXT_MESSAGE_IN_HERE',
        'channel': '#{YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME_WITHOUT_CURLY_BRACKETS}'
}
```